# Picasso showing error while loading images(Album Cover Pic) from MediaStore

Tags: android, cursor, picasso, mediastore

I am trying to load images in a recycler View using Picasso using the code

```
Picasso.with(context).load(songs.CoverArtAlbumPath.get(position)).into(holder.primaryImageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.v("abc","suc");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.v("abc","err");
            }
        });
```

And it always ends up in onError() method. I tried to load the images using the traditional way by using BitmapFactory.decodeFile and other methods and then it was working fine.

The songs.CoverArtAlbumPath.get(position) contain strings like as **"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1456505346363"**

I also tried to load an image from the drawable folder by just changing the .load() parameters in the Picasso code and it got loaded. That means no error in the context and ImageView I am using here.

**The string which I am passing in the .load() method is the string path for the Cover Art of the Album from the MediaStore.**

The ImageView used here is the View in the following xml code 
      `<ImageView
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>`

Please Help to tell that what is wrong and what should I do to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 for showing image with storage path:

      String path ="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/145650‌​5346363.png";

      Picasso.with(mContext).load("file://" + path)
      //.transform(new util.CircleTransform())// optional
      //.placeholder(R.drawable.default1) // optional
      .error(R.drawable.default1)   // optional
      .into(holder.primaryImageView);

 for showing image from url:

    String url ="http://www.domain_name.com/image.png";
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(url)
            //.placeholder(R.drawable.default1) // optional
            .error(R.drawable.default1)   // optional
            //.transform(new CircleTransform())// optional
            .into(holder.primaryImageView);
```

Comment: I am able to load it from the drawable folder even as R.drawable.Image but the problem is when the .load() parameter is string.

Comment: are you sure for path. url having "http://" before domain name.. please check my update as above.

Comment: The string is "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1456505346363" like this

Comment: ok,then, you can use..  Picasso.with(mContext).load("file://" + path)
      //.transform(new util.CircleTransform())// optional
      //.placeholder(R.drawable.default1) // optional
      .error(R.drawable.default1)   // optional
      .into(holder.primaryImageView);

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!!! That "file://" did it :D Thanks. Edit it in ur answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong try this

```
String path ="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/145650‌​5346363.png";

Picasso.with(context).load(new File(path)).into(holder.primaryImageView);
```

For more Information go to http://square.github.io/picasso/